# Call a function defined in an external javascript function from vb.net code behind (.html not .aspx)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a plain `.html` page which has a `hiddenField` and a reference to `External.js`. Since I am implementing using `ASP.NET`, server side will execute first. However, I need to execute a function in `External.js` before server code execution. The solution is available by the having the following code:

*In .aspx ***

```
<script src="External.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />`
```

**In .aspx.vb**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Try
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "register", "MyFunction();", True)
End If
Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
 End Sub
```

The code works perfectly when I am using a `.aspx` page. Obviously, I cannot use any `ASP.NET` server controls in a plain `.html` page. So using `<asp:ScriptManager>` in a `.html` page will not work. How  can I do the same exact thing **but** in an `.html` page. What should be defined in the `.html page` and how can I call the function from the code behind, keeping in mind that I cannot use any `<asp:>` controls.

Ok so what I am trying to do is that I have my `External.js` which has the function `populateHidden()` which basically sets a value to my `hiddenField`.

```
function populateHidden()
{
document.getElementByID('Hidden').value = "abcdefg";
}
```

I also have another function `PassData()` which basically initializes an `ajax request` to the server to pass the value of `Hidden` to the code behind (using a webMethod). The problem is that I want `populateHidden()` to execute first so that `passData()` passes `abcdefg` (after `populateHidden()` is executed) to the code behind to store the value in a database. So currently the way I am running both functions is as follows.

**in .html**

`<body onload="PassData()">`

**in code-behind**

trying to execute `populateHidden();` on `Page_Load` since server side executes first.

Comment: .html files don't have code behind as they are just html.  You can't execute client side code before the server has rendered a page in asp.net because the client would not have received the generated html yet.  Can you give a more concrete example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: You write: "However, I need to execute a function in `External.js` before server code execution." Plain HTML code doesn't have server execution, so it's unclear to me what you're trying to do. Instead of couching things in terms of ASP.NET, just say what you're trying to do, like: "I want javascript to insert an image tag in my HTML before the page renders" or something like that. All your ASP.NET comparisons are confusing the issue since this isn't an ASP.NET issue.

Comment: There is no Page_Load on an HTML file.  If you're talking about an ASPX page, then why not just render <body onload="PassData('abcdefg')">?

Comment: @Andorbal I do know that there is no `Page_Load` in an `HTML` File, I did mention it under the code-behind section in my post. I cannot pass the data through `PassData()` because `Hidden` is not static, instead its changing. So I NEED TO EXECUTE `populateHidden()` first and then `passData()` second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I borrowed this from @Cleydson's answer:

**JS**

```
function MyFunction()
{
    populateHidden();
    PassData();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="External.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body onload="MyFunction();">
...
</body>
```

Now you're calling `populateHidden()` **before** `PassData()`

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if I understood it correctly. But, if you want do call a script in the same way you’ve done you just need to do it:

```
<body onload="MyFunction();">
```

complete version:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="External.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="MyFunction();">
    ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Is it?

Comment: Yes but the problem is that I have two functions mentioned at the end of my post and I need `populateHidden()` to be executed before `passData()` and I mentioned how they are currently executed.

Comment: Ok. humm. You edited and made it clear. I think @Andorbal clarified you right?